# Bootstrap 3 datetime picker

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap 3 datetime picker for my project. the datetime picker should be append on end of the code. should not append on after input field. It works but not positioning rightly. What function i need to written for in this case?

http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 
    
    
});
```

```html
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div>        
       <label>Date and Time</label>      
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't get you, what exactly you want? Please explain in breif ( **`edit question`** )

Comment: The date picker need to append end of the body

Comment: The date picker dropdown menu should be append on end of the body (</body)

Comment: are you looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/2233/

Comment: Please refer the link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PTaef.jpg

Comment: lIke data-container="body"

Comment: You don't want it outside the body, or it won't be on the website